# Последняя проблема с INNER JOIN

Tags: объединение, mysql

Снова. Есть таблицы:

- tasks - http://clip2net.com/clip/m40641/1364482491-clip-52kb.png
- tasks_categories - http://clip2net.com/clip/m40641/1364482446-clip-3kb.png
- tasks_categories_ent - http://clip2net.com/clip/m40641/1364546112-clip-5kb.png

Есть код, который соединяет эти 3 таблицы и выходит всё, как надо:

```
INNER JOIN `tasks` ON users.vk_id = tasks.tvk_id LEFT OUTER JOIN tasks_categories_ent ON tasks_categories_ent.tce_eid = tasks.tid LEFT OUTER JOIN tasks_categories ON tasks_categories.tc_id = tasks_categories_ent.tce_cid
```

В данный момент из **tasks** выводятся все записи, то есть 50. Но есть проблема, если в **tasks_categories_ent** в поле **tce_eid** имеется 2 одинаковых числа, но с разными пользователями, то материал из **tasks** с этим id начинает дублироваться. Мне нужно просто добавить к запросу WHERE `tasks_categories_ent.tce_vk_id = 156650173` например. Но тогда выводятся вообще 2 записи, так как видимо в tasks_categories_ent 2 записи с этим vk_id. Как же всё наладить?

**Вот мой код с WHERE, который выводит 2 записи:**

```
INNER JOIN `tasks` ON users.vk_id = tasks.tvk_id LEFT OUTER JOIN tasks_categories_ent ON tasks_categories_ent.tce_eid = tasks.tid LEFT OUTER JOIN tasks_categories ON tasks_categories.tc_id = tasks_categories_ent.tce_cid WHERE tasks_categories_ent.tce_vk_id = 156650173
```

Comment: не в тему, но почему всегда, когда кто-то приводит sql запрос, он его не форматирует. Ведь сплошной текст не особо так удобно читать. Или такая проблема только у меня?

Comment: @teanЫЧ, я просто не знаю, как правильно это делать..) Если подскажете, я исправлюсь!

Comment: Стиль кодирования у каждого свой. Не мешало бы например переносить смысловые блоки

    INNER JOIN `tasks` ON users.vk_id = tasks.tvk_id 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN tasks_categories_ent ON tasks_categories_ent.tce_eid = tasks.tid 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN tasks_categories ON tasks_categories.tc_id = tasks_categories_ent.tce_cid 
    WHERE tasks_categories_ent.tce_vk_id = 156650173

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, нужно как-то так:

>> LEFT OUTER JOIN tasks_categories ON tasks_categories.tc_id = tasks_categories_ent.tce_cid AND tasks_categories.tc_vk_id = 156650173

но

>> AND tasks_categories.tc_vk_id = 156650173

не принимает. Ошибка :(

Comment: Вашу структуру и запрос на http://sqlfiddle.com. Собирать инфу по комментариям и угадывать какая у вас ошибка очень сложно и прямо скажем лениво.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, не надо угадывать. Нужно просто как-то соединить. Что-то типа такого:

>> ON tasks_categories.tc_id = tasks_categories_ent.tce_cid || tasks_categories.tc_vk_id = 156650173

но это неправильно.

Comment: пффф. ну, соединяйте.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, как?. Как только не пробывал. И ничего не работает!

>>ON tasks_categories.tc_id = tasks_categories_ent.tce_cid INNER JOIN tasks_categories.tc_vk_id = 156650173

>>ON tasks_categories.tc_id = tasks_categories_ent.tce_cid JOIN tasks_categories.tc_vk_id = 156650173

>> ON tasks_categories.tc_id = tasks_categories_ent.tce_cid ON tasks_categories.tc_vk_id = 156650173

>> ON tasks_categories.tc_id = tasks_categories_ent.tce_cid AND tasks_categories.tc_vk_id = 156650173

>> ON tasks_categories.tc_id = tasks_categories_ent.tce_cid || tasks_categories.tc_vk_id = 156650173

Comment: Ничего не работает - это жалоба "пользователя ПК". документацию почитайте, раз выкладывать не хотите.  
ЗЫ может быть OR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Указать, что необходимо выбрать неповторяющиеся записи

```
SELECT DISTINCT tasks.* ...
```

совет: применяйте короткие алиасы для имен таблиц - читать запрос станет проще

Comment: @renegator, в таблице tasks то нет повторов. Это уже join химичит.

Comment: Выборка неповторяющихся записей происходит не из таблицы а из всего кортежа. Предложение DISTINCT tasks.* говорит, что уникальность рассчитывается по все колонкам, которые в итоговый кортеж пришли из таблицы tasks

Comment: @renegator, как его применить, когда начало запроса такое: 

>> SELECT users.rate, tasks.tid, tasks.tcategory, tasks.tname, tasks.turl, tasks.tfile_text, tasks.tcount, tasks.tdone_users, tasks.tprice, tasks.trepost, tasks.tcomments, tasks.top, tasks_categories_ent.tce_id, tasks_categories_ent.tce_vk_id, tasks_categories_ent.tce_eid, tasks_categories.tc_name

?

Comment: У меня clip2net закрыт файрволлом. Полностью запрос как выглядит? Вместе с предложением FROM. И расставьте уже алиасы таблиц, в глазах мельтешит

Comment: @renegator, как расставлять, не знаю:

>> http://pastebin.com/MZms1gr8

Comment: ха. Наш корпоративный файрволл на фуфле не проведешь. У него есть категория "сетевые хранилища"
ну например так

    SELECT u.rate, t.*, ent.tce_id, ent.tce_vk_id, ent.tce_eid, с.tc_name
    FROM users u
       INNER JOIN `tasks` t ON u.vk_id = t.tvk_id 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN tasks_categories_ent ent ON ent.tce_eid = t.tid 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN tasks_categories с ON c.tc_id = ent.tce_cid 
     WHERE ent.tce_vk_id = 156650173

Comment: @renegator, вообще не понимаю Ваш код. Нет DISTINCT, что такое t.* непонятно. Скорее это не то ><

Comment: это пример расстановки алиасов

Comment: Если в выборке участвуют поля неограниченной длины, то distinct не поможет. Надо делать два запроса.